# Android HTTP 403 error when connectiong to server

Tags: android, http, http-status-code-403

I have a server connection to send some images to a server I have. But I'm getting a 403 error when trying to access the server. Initially the code works, but after sending some images it starts to give error 403.

This is my code:

```
 class enviarImagensOutros extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://aqua-info.net/backupDados.php?").openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            bufferedWriter.write("idUser=" + idUser + "&myJsonArray=" + imagemFinal + "&act=teste&data=" + currentDateandTime);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            connection.connect();

            int response = connection.getResponseCode();
            // indica se a opracao de guardar os dados no servidor correu bem ou nao
            if (response >= 200 && response <= 399) {

                return true;
            } else {
                
            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
            
        } finally {
            
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I do it so I don't get the error 403?

Comment: 403 is unauthorized, that's a problem on your server

Comment: also, this question really doesn't have anything to do with android studio

Comment: But why dose it work for some images with this same http connection, and after a time stops working?

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 occurs when your HTTP request gets forbidden. Debug your code and check whether you are calling the request which you are now authorized